# Any mechanism prevent execv from service

Tags: linux, mips, iot, exploit

I am developing POC of chimay red exploit from Vault 7 CIA Leaks.
I can run any shell code at target router except execv.
When executes excecv system call, the www service dies(or is killed?) immediately.
I don't know why this happens, and how to overcome it.
Someone told me, "My guess is that there was a mechanism which monitor the service and kills it when it does not responds."
I'm not sure if such mechanism exists in linux or not.
Can anyone explain the correct reason this happens?

Comment: How far into the execv are you getting? Execv does a lot, can you look at the router kernel side like in emulator?

Comment: Mechanism? If you are trying to do execve in the stack (NX protection), or maybe you don't know the address where is your shellcode (ASLR, PIC). Also, you can disable some system calls using libseccomp.